# Xcode 7 : set top constraint for CollectionView for iPhone 6S plus

Tags: ios, storyboard, constraints, xcode7, nslayoutconstraint

I want to set **different constraints based on device type.**
The constraint is to be set b/w CollectionView and Label (Username)

**For eg.** `iPhone 4 will have top: 2 left: 0 right: 0 and bottom:0`

whereas 
`iPhone 6S Plus will have top: 15 left: 0 right: 0 and bottom:0`

[image: Screenshot 1]

How can this be set in Storyboard?

Comment: use size-classes in IB, that does the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can create an outlet for the top constraint and change the value in code

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint    
                                    *collectionViewTopSpaceConstraint;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //iPhone 6 plus
    if(CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) == 736.0)
    {
       self.collectionViewTopSpaceConstraint.constant = 10; // some constant
    }



}
```

Comment: size-classes are much more elegant ways to resolve such problem. your suggestion is a bit yesterday.